# View taking space after hiding

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility

I made one TextView and set it's visibility to invisible. so it's working fine in terms of hiding but when the set the gravity to center for the remaining elements they leave a free space for that hidden view.

Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
 android:setvisibility="gone"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.

- `INVISIBLE` - layout will take its height and width but is not visible only
- `GONE` - layout will invisible and it also not hold space for height and width.